# "RVM is not a function" error when running in ruby script and irb

Tags: ruby, rvm

I get an error when I run `%x{rvm use @myapp}` in ruby and irb. The error is "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work".

Here's what I've tried:
1. the "rvm use @myapp" command works in OSX command prompt (using OSX Mavericks)
2. made sure RVM is the latest version.
3. reloaded RVM check RVM is a function in the command prompt
4. (still fails in irb and ruby's `%x{}`)
5. According to some SO posts, I changed OSX terminal preferences from login shell to `/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash --login`. Quit, opened new terminal windows but all efforts were in vain.
6. checked .bash_profile for `[[-s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

Any ideas on how I can get `%x{rvm use @myapp}` to work in ruby and irb?

Comment: I've looked into this a bit and it seems that Ruby launches a new subshell to run system commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
%x{bash -c 'source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"; rvm use @myapp'}
```

However, you really can use `rvm` as you've specified because even if you've set up the `rvm` you then lost your session because your terminal will be closed. Try to setup your environment with `session` gem, and control *bash* session with it.

```
require 'session'

@myapp = 'ruby-1.8.7-p374'

bash = Session::Bash.new

stdout, stderr = bash.execute 'source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'

stdout, stderr = bash.execute "rvm use #{@myapp}"
puts stdout

# => Using /home/malo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374
```

Comment: it makes not much sense as the loaded environment is lost right after finishing this command

Comment: Of course, because `%x{}` just `exec` spawns new process, runs the commend in its shell, and when exits. You may to redescribe yor task, to make it closer to your real needs.

Comment: @LajosVeres since the dialogue has begun here, it does no make sense to move it elsethere.

Comment: @LajosVeres and this of course provided exact answer to the question without throws to right or left side, and without arrivals at.

Comment: the added part  is what `rvm-with` gem does in background (with extra checks and improvements) => https://github.com/mpapis/rvm-with

Comment: The `%x{bash -c ...}` worked great for me and was simpler. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What happens here is that the `shell` you had started `ruby` or `irb` with had `rvm` defined both as a `function` and added to `PATH` the function takes precedence in shell and it all worked fine, but when you open `ruby` or `irb` it is a new process and it inherits only environment variables which includes `PATH` and does not inherit functions, additionally running `%x{}` from ruby creates another shell process which is neither a login or interactive shell, and they respectively would make shell load `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc`.

Depending on what do you want to do you have few options, to execute another `ruby`/`gem` you can use `rvm ... do ...` for from `%x{}` like this:

```
rvm @myapp do ruby -e '...'
```

OR:

```
rvm @myapp do gem install ...
```

OR:

```
rvm @myapp do bundle install
```

it allows single command to run in the context of given ruby

Comment: Could you explain a little more how to implement this option in a ruby file? Are you saying in my `my_magic_file.rb`, I put:  `rvm @myapp do ruby -e '%x{gem install some_gem; bundle install}' end`?

Comment: Thanks for explanation of what happens under-the-hood. I chose to go with the @majioa answer because it was more straight forward and second I notice a slower response when using the `rvm ... do ...` statement in the command line vs `rvm use @myapp; ...`